# How to add behavoirs to asp.net mvc 2 action result output

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, actionresult

Lets say I have two controllers and two actions.

Controller - > AController
Action -> MethodA()

.

Controller - > BController
Action -> MethodB()

Both of these return xml data by a View(typedObject).

I want to add base 64 encoding before returning this output to the client. On MethodA and MethodB. And there might be some other methods that should be included in this encoding aswell.

Would there be any good way of accomplish an behavoir / treatment of the action result ?

Would it be best to add a custom Action Result for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your action with an [action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232768.aspx)

Comment: Is it 'correct' that an ActionFilter should know about the UI / Rendering?, it doesnt feel good.

Comment: Is it 'correct' that an ActionFilter should know about the UI / Rendering?, it doesnt feel good, since the controller should have no knowledge how the information is rendered. And the transform to xml is actually done in the view.